# Restoring a class in parse

Tags: parse-platform

I had a class that I created in Pares that was holding emails for a email signup list. I made the mistake of deleting the entire class and not a few rows that had test data in them. Is there a way to restore that class in Parse?

Comment: You can get the class back by manually creating it again. As for the data that was stored, it's gone. Bad luck.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Not possible. Since you yourself deleted it, the data is gone. I would suggest you to export your data at frequent intervals to prevent such a loss (in future).